# Best Practices for Claims

Tags: .net, owin, claims-based-identity

Microsoft default login system uses ClaimTypes.Name to store the e-mail and ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier to store the UID of an user (and also a SecurityStamp for additional control). Some other samples use ClaimTypes.Name to store the full name of the user. I know I can use custom login system as I wish, but as I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel, I have some questions as follows:

1. What's the purpose of NameIdentifier vs Sid vs PrimaryId?
2. What's the purpose of Name vs (GivenName + Surname)?
3. Should I put the login e-mail address in ClaimTypes.Email?
4. In case of a custom user name (not an e-mail address) should I create a custom claim like "username"?